# Use SAS to access files in Azure

Tags: python, azure, azure-storage

I'm trying to access files in Azure from Python with a URL like this: URL: https://devlifemoorstorage.file.core.windows.net/varamptest?st=2021-06-24T09%3A03%3A48Z&se=2021-08-31T09%3A03%3A00Z&sp=rl&sv=2018-03-28&sr=s&sig=hrBBwAZ8xCy4Nuf7YibsUaQdKwcy3hOoXbUZzRkdyLw%3D
or a Query string like this: ?st=2021-06-24T09%3A03%3A48Z&se=2021-08-31T09%3A03%3A00Z&sp=rl&sv=2018-03-28&sr=s&sig=hrBBwAZ8xCy4Nuf7YibsUaQdKwcy3hOoXbUZzRkdyLw%3D. How do I do this?

I tried to follow this example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-python-how-to-use-file-storage?tabs=python , but they used something called "connection string" which I'm not sure of the format of.

What is the format of connection string, or alternatively, how can I use the SAS URL / Query string directly to access the files in Python?

Comment: Please do not attach the [SAS] tag to questions that have nothing to do with SAS software.

Comment: Sorry, it was a mistake, but it seems that I can't change it now.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an instance of `ShareClient` using this SAS URL. The method you would want to use is [`from_share_url`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/python/api/azure-storage-file-share/azure.storage.fileshare.shareclient?view=azure-python#from-share-url-share-url--snapshot-none--credential-none----kwargs-). Your code would look something like:

```
share_client = ShareClient.from_share_url(sas_url)
```

Once you have the share_client, you can perform operations on your share. Considering you only have `read` and `list` permissions in your SAS, you will only be able to [`list files and directories`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/python/api/azure-storage-file-share/azure.storage.fileshare.shareclient?view=azure-python#list-directories-and-files-directory-name-none--name-starts-with-none--marker-none----kwargs-) and read share properties for that share.

Using this `share_client`, you can also create an instance of `FileClient` or `DirectoryClient` using [`get_file_client`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/python/api/azure-storage-file-share/azure.storage.fileshare.shareclient?view=azure-python#get-file-client-file-path-) or [`get_directory_client`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/python/api/azure-storage-file-share/azure.storage.fileshare.shareclient?view=azure-python#get-directory-client-directory-path-none-) methods and perform read and list operations on files and directories.

Something like:

```
file_client = share_client.get_file_client('file-name')
...do some operations on file using this file client
```

Comment: Thanks! How do I download/read the file using the share_client?

Comment: You can't using share_client to download the file. You will need to use `file_client` and then use [`download_file`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/python/api/azure-storage-file-share/azure.storage.fileshare.sharefileclient?view=azure-python#download-file-offset-none--length-none----kwargs-) to download the file.